# how to add local jar to maven project

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, jar, db2

I trying a small maven project, and I try to connect to db2 database, so I need the  `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver` jar for the connection.

I tried many method from internet but still fail, here is some of the method I tried:

1. edit in pom.xml

   ```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
           <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
           <version>10.5.0.7</version>
           <scope>system</scope>
           <systemPath>
               /home/Workspace/book/springData/lib/db2jcc4-10.5.0.7.jar
           </systemPath>
       </dependency>
   ```
2. use maven command to install:

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/Workspace/book/springData/lib/db2jcc4-10.5.0.7.jar -DpomFile=/home/Workspace/book/springData/pom.xml
   ```

   or

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/meow/Workspace/mbsb-cib/springData/lib/db2jcc4-10.5.0.7.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 -DartifactId=db2jcc4 -Dversion=10.5.0.7 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   ```

But, I am still hitting could not load JDBC driver.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:150)
    at com.journaldev.spring.config.DataConfig.dataSource(DataConfig.java:52)
    at com.journaldev.spring.config.DataConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46013fb.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>)
    at com.journaldev.spring.config.DataConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46013fb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8fec3ead.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at com.journaldev.spring.config.DataConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46013fb.dataSource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver from [Module "deployment.springData.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:147)
    ... 82 more
```

Comment: The system scope is marked as deprecated. Here is a guide that describe a method to install the local jar to the local maven repository and use it as a normal maven dependency. Although I have never tried it, it might worth a shot: https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2014/06/10/maven-include-system-scope-dependency-in-maven-assembly-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the reference from central repository in pom.xml?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2.jcc/db2jcc4 -->
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
     <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
     <version>10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Once you add this please rebuild your project with maven.

Or if you want to proceed from local disk : [click here to view the answer in stackoverflow itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project)